# DataGrid and comboBox with 2 different collections.Is it possible?

Tags: wpf

HI all

I have a form with a list of Customers.

Selecting a customer brings another form with a datagrid filled with "BooksBoughtByCustomer" with a datatemplate with a combobox.

My Problem is this

Populate a datagrid with all the books bought by the customer.
Clicking on the comboBox however should list "AllBooksAvailable"

Again
Basically the selectedItem in the combo should be one of the book bought by the customer

selecting the dropdown should list all books.

When I load my form "MVVM" is used I have 2 collections

1. CustomerBooks
2. AllBooks

below is my attempt but obviously wrong.
I am kind of lost how to do this.Can You give me some suggestions or some pseudocode as a start up point?

```
       <DataGrid
            x:Name="dgCustomerBooks"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"             
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=SelectedCustomer.CustomerBooks}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn
                Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=Strings.Title, Mode=OneTime}">                                
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox
                            x:Name="cboBooks"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}, Path=SelectedCustomer.AllBooks}"
                            MinWidth="100">                                                        
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                            
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the 'customer's books' a subset of 'all books' ?
In which case, set the Combobox's itemsSource property to 'all books' and set the selected item by finding the specific book within this collection.

Or am I missing something here...
Update:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WPF_Sandbox:Book}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</StackPanel.Resources>
<ComboBox  x:Name="cbo"  ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBook}"/>
```

The ViewModel has 2 properties - Books and SelectedBook.
where SelectedBook selects one from the list of Books using some criteria like

```
    this.Books = new[] { new Book{Id=1, Name="Book1"},
                         new Book{Id=2, Name="Book2"},
                         new Book{Id=3, Name="Book3"}};
    this.SelectedBook = Books.Where(book => book.Id == 2).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply."Customer's book" is a subset of all books.The comboBox's ItemsSource is already set to all books.Would it be possible for you to give an example of Setting the selectedItem by finding the specific book within collection? Sorry if I dont understand something you explain so clearly.  I can do eg books.Where(x=>x.book.Title==?

Comment: @user231- added code snippet. you can replace the Id == 2 with any arbitrary condition like Title == customer.Title

Comment: Gishu.Thanks for your time.Really appreaciated.I have done something similar but still does not work.The xaml is exactly like yours.   I load this form,now I have 2 collections "AllBooks" and "BooksBoughtByCustomers".I was doing        foreach (var bookBought in BooksBoughtByCustomer)
            {
               SelectedBook = AllBooks.Where(x=>x.BookId=BookBought.BookId).SingleOrDefault();
            }     but this was settings all the rows and combos in the datagrid to the same item. Not sure if expressing myself properly but each row in datagrid will have a different selected item.

Comment: Really stuck on this one.really appreciate your help

Comment: @user231 - So for the customer books popup, you should have a ViewModel which contains a collection of GridRowVMs. each GridRowVM should have the Book property set to a different Book from Customer-bought-books- via code while creating the GridRowVMs. Next define the DataGridComboBoxColumn to bind ItemsSource to AllCustomerBooks (which should be a shared static list someplace) and SelectedItem={Binding Book}. see this link if you're using the wpf datagrid - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/10/31/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboboxcolumn-v1-intro.aspx